# Any idea on how this 36 character long string generated?

Tags: cryptography, hash, forensics, random, string

I have a personal id "U1KFhYtMqZhCYya6sy31PVLM8DlM5HLCkwy3", I have checked some hash functions but cannot make sure how this generated? Is this just random string generated with [a-zA-z0-9]?

Comment: It is impossible to decide based on a single sample if this sample was taken from a random distribution or not - or even which deterministic process produced this sample.

Comment: If cryptographic processes are used, then it will be difficult to determine if it is random or the result of a process.

Comment: OP, if you are looking for a command to generate a random string containing 36 uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits, the following command will do the trick:  `head /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alpha:][:digit:]' | cut -c 1-36`